# Unable to put line numbers in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to put line numbers in Visual Studio.
Usually I go for
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C#

A new machine was assigned to me with preinstalled VS 2008. I am unable to find the C# option.

Any solution ? Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: There is really something messed up. Normally you have a lot of more options in the left panel. Go to Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio.
Theres a list of all installed products, is C# missing there too? Maybe reinstall or repair  fixes the problem.

Comment: For years, people complain that Visual Studio is too complicated. Then they go and try to simplify it, and people start complaining that they can't find their favorite features. Glad I'm not in software development, that would be a nightmare! Oh wait...

Comment: @AntiLamir.  I checked..C# is present..I followed instructions from Gavin , Code Gray and issue is fixed...Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to check the box labeled **"Show all settings"** in the lower left-hand corner.

Then, you can expand "Text Editor", select "C#", and check "Line numbers". (You can also enable this setting for *all* languages, rather than individual ones, if you prefer.)

[image: Visual Studio Options dialog]

And while you're at it, you probably want to crank up "Animate environment tools" to the max. No point in waiting around on the IDE to show pretty animations when you have code to write!

Comment: OT, but you have an interesting UI scheme

Comment: @Marc: Yeah, it's clashing with the background color the VS IDE. It's actually a much prettier pink. What can I say? I like colors, and I got bored of all the normal ones. It was also season appropriate for Valentines Day, but I've been too lazy to change it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check the "Show All Settings" checkbox at the bottom of the dialog. It should then show all supported languages, although you may be better setting "All Languages" rather than setting it for each individual language..